# How to always show decimal part when using DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, decimalformat

```
Float sum = new Float(300); // always somehow calculated
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
String s = df.format(sum/3);  // prints 100, I want 100.0
s = df.format(301/3); // pritns 100.3 which is correct
```

Result should always be formatted to 1 decimal palce, how to do so?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Change

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
```

to

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
```

Basically, a 0 means "always show the digit in this position", where a # means "show the digit in this position unless it's zero".

Comment: btw if result is 0 and formating is ("#.0") result will be nothing? should I use ("0.0") instead?

Comment: then you will get .0 if the result is 0. If you always want 0.0 then you should change it to ("0.0");

Comment: yes I needed to wait 10 mins since asking or something like that ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can read about the patterns [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Change the following line to should do the trick.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
```